# php get element position in array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, position

i try get position of element in my array but this not work,
this is my code:

```
<?php
function getWorldRank(){
$query = ("SELECT nickname FROM users ORDER BY score, updateDate Desc ");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

//GOES TO THE DB WITH THE QUERY
$result = mysql_query($query);

//CHECKS IF THE QUERY IS LEGAL
if(!$result)
return false;

//CHECKS IF THERE ARE NO ROWS FOUND IN THE TABLE
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
return false;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
         $returned_array[] = $row;
    }
    return $returned_array;

       }

      $a=getWorldRank();



    echo $key = array_search('vvvv', $a); 
    echo $key = array_search('bbbb', $a); 

 ?>
```

Comment: So you've written buggy code and expect us to fix your bugs for you? That's not how it works

Comment: $a is an array of arrays. You need to search each array in $a, not $a itself.

Comment: you are returning before your the array_search...

Comment: i dont understand what wrong in my code. when i print array i can see all elements

Comment: i guess the entire thing is inside function called getWorldRank() and he returns array from there.

Comment: Before being able to claim something is "not working" one must first establish a definition of what "working" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getWorldRank() {
  $query = ("SELECT nickname FROM users ORDER BY score, updateDate Desc ");
  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

  //GOES TO THE DB WITH THE QUERY
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  // CHECKS IF THE QUERY IS LEGAL
  if(!$result) {
    return false;
  }

  // CHECKS IF THERE ARE NO ROWS FOUND IN THE TABLE
  if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    return false;
  }

  $returned_array = array();

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $returned_array[] = $row['nickname'];
  }
  return $returned_array;
}

$a = getWorldRank();

if(!$a) {
  print 'No results returned by database';
} else {
  echo 'vvvv key: ' . array_search('vvvv', $a); 
  echo 'bbbb key: ' . array_search('bbbb', $a); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change one line:

```
$returned_array[] = $row;
```

to

```
$returned_array[] = $row['nickname'];
```

then you will be returning an array, not an array of arrays.